# Hausdorff measure of the middle third Cantor set and Compactness

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, fractals, geometric-measure-theory

In the proof of the Hausdorff dimension of the middle third cantor set I cannot understand why we need the following underlined statement. I cannot understand why we need only consider closed intervals? Moreover, I am not sure in the construction why we would include/exclude the end points of the intervals.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this proof $|U|$ is the diameter of $U$. It isn't hard to see that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there and any set $U$ with finite diameter there is an open interval $V$ with the property that $U \subset V$ and $|V| = (1 + \epsilon)|U|$. To see this, observe that if $U$ has finite diameter then $U$ is bounded, $U \subset [\inf U, \sup U]$, and $|U| = \sup U - \inf U$. Define $V = (\inf U - \delta,\sup U + \delta)$ where $\delta > 0$ is chosen so that $|V| = |U| + 2\delta  = (1 + \epsilon)|U|$.

Let $\{U_i\}$ be a cover of $F$ by sets with finite diameter. Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given and select the $\{V_i\}$ accordingly. Since $F$ is compact there exists an index $I$ so that $\{V_i\}_{i=1}^I$ is a cover of $F$. If in this instance you can verify that $\sum_{i=1}^I |V_i|^s \ge 3^{-s}$ you will obtain
$$
(1+\epsilon)\sum_i |U_i|^s =  \sum_i |V_i|^s \ge  \sum_i |V_i|^s \ge 3^{-s}
$$
for the arbitrary cover. Then let $\epsilon \to 0^+$.

Comment: I dont understand your second from last sentence starting with "If in this instance...."

Comment: Your underlined text includes the phrase "we need only verify (2.14) if $\{U_i\}$ is a finite collection of closed subintervals of $[0,1]$". If you can prove the inequality for the finite collection $\{\overline U_i\}$ the argument I sketched shows how to obtain the general inequality

Comment: Sorry could you clarify how this creates a set of $\underline{closed \ intervals}$?

Comment: 1) Cover $F$ by arbitrary closed intervals $\{U_i\}$.
2) Define $V_i$ by enlarging $U_i$ accordingly.
3) $\{V_i\}$ is an open cover of $F$ so it reduces to a finite subcover $\{V_i\}_{i=1}^N$.
4) $\{\overline{V_i}\}_{i=1}^N$ is a finite cover of $F$ by closed intervals. 
5) $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^N |\overline{V_i}|^s \ge 3^{-s}$.

Comment: Why do we need to verify that $\sum_{i=1}^I |V_i|^s \ge 3^{-s}$? Arent we verifying that $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^N |\overline{V_i}|^s \ge 3^{-s}$ ? Surely if we could verify that $\sum_{i=1}^I |V_i|^s \ge 3^{-s}$ holds we could just say that closed set would be slightly bigger